# How to Find a Fugitive Crontab

Tags: cron

A few years ago I setup a cron job to automatically ping a URL every minute as part of a monitoring system (that's oversimplification, but it'll do for this question). Because I'm a horrible person, I didn't document this anywhere.

Today, years later, I started having trouble with the application on the other end of the URL that's being pinged.  I fixed it, but then realized, **I have no idea where this cron job is coming from**.

Is there a way to quickly search through or cat out all the crontabs on a particular system?  I have root access so permissions aren't a problem.  I've only ever been a user of `cron`, I've never looked too deeply at its implementation, but my *nix instincts say there has to be a group of text files somewhere that hold all the crontabs.  I just don't know where they'd be, and if I dug into it I'd be afraid of finding some, but not all of them, or missing some weird nuance of the system

Also, I realize with root access I could

1. Get a list of all the users in the system
2. `su` as a user
3. `crontab -l`
4. Repeat with all the users

but I'm looking for something a little less manual (and looking to learn something about cron's implementation)

Comment: you might need to look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are only a few places crontabs can hide:

- `/etc/crontab`
- `/etc/cron.d/*`
- `/etc/crond.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}/*`
  *these are called from `/etc/crontab`, so maybe an asterisk on this*
- `/var/spool/cron/*` (sometimes `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/*`)

Be sure to check `at` as well, which keeps its jobs in `/var/spool/at/` or `/var/spool/cron/at*/`

Also, instead of

```
su <user>
crontab -l
```

Just do this:

```
crontab -lu <user>
```

Answer (score 8):

Crontabs live in `/etc/crontab` and (with many implementations) its components in `/etc/cron.*/*` (all edited by root), and in `/var/spool/cron/*` (users' crontabs).

If you have trouble locating the offending job, another approach is to investigate one while it's going on. For example, you can add a firewall rule to log the user id of the process opening connections to `example.com` on port 80:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --syn -d example.com --dport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix "[->example.com] " --log-uid
```

If the job is using an application such as `ping` or `curl`, shadow the usual binary by a wrapper that logs information about what is using it, with a script like this one in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
#!/bin/sh
{
  date
  echo "$0" "$@"
  ps -p $PPID
  echo
} >>"/tmp/$(basename "$0").log"
exec "/usr/bin/$(basename "$0")" "$@"
```

Comment: +1 because it shows how to get the problem to explain itself!

Answer (score 6):

The quick and dirty way:

```
grep -r ping /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

The exact location where *crontabs* are stored may vary from system to system, but it's generally in `/var/spool` and has `crontab` somewhere in the name.

Also note that many systems have *system* crontabs (like in `/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.d`) some of which may call more scripts like `/etc/cron.hourly`, `.daily`...

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like a cronjob that was created by crontab. Not all crontabs have a `-u` switch, but for GNU/Linux it is available. This is a handy line to list all cronjobs created by crontab.

```
for user in $(awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done
```

(Run as root.)

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, you can make a honeypot out of URL it's requesting -- i.e. serve a large file or something -- and look for the process that's waiting to receive the data, and then look up its PPID.

Answer (score 2):

Any decent system should explain the precise location of the crontabs in the manpage (usually in the `FILES` section near the end, and also for other dæmons).

On my system for instance, `cron(8)` contains the following:

```
 FILES
      /etc/crontab          system crontab file
      /var/cron/atjobs      directory containing at(1) jobs
      /var/cron/log         cron's log file
      /var/cron/tabs        directory containing individual crontab files
      /var/cron/tabs/.sock  used by crontab(1) to tell cron to check for
                            crontab changes immediately
```

And I second tylerl's advice to also check for `at` jobs while you're at it.

Answer (score 2):

Approaching it the other way ’round:  cron keeps a log of what it is doing, precisely to avoid this kind of problems in the first place.  On my system, the log is kept in `/var/cron/log` and looks like this:

```
==> /var/cron/log <==
Oct 25 00:21:01 fortress cron[20232]: (vucar) CMD (/home/vucar/lighttpd-watchdog)
```

This line tells me that the cron instance with PID 20232 on machine `fortress` is executing `/home/vucar/lighttpd-watchdog` on behalf of user `vucar`.  A well-behaved system only has a single cron running, so this will be straightforward.

This also works for `at` jobs, as they’re usually just handed to cron anyway:

```
==> /var/cron/log <==
Oct 25 00:28:01 fortress cron[31282]: (vucar) ATJOB (1414189680.c)
```

The snippets are from a BSD system, but the general concept is very likely the same everywhere else.